# In pinescript, how do I draw a horizontal line of the 9:30am open candle price and extend that line to 1600pm but no further? (5m timeframe)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to draw a horizontal line at the price of the open of the 9:30am candle and extend it to 1600pm. I want this line to be draw on Mondays to Fridays from 9:30am to 16:00

I can get the line, but Im not sure how to extend it to only 1600, and for it to show up on every other previous 9:30 to 16:00

```
indicator("Extended Open Line", overlay=true)

IsSessionStart(sessionTime, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    inSess = not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, sessionTimeZone))
    inSess and not inSess[1]

var float RDROpen = na

if IsSessionStart("0930-1030:2345", "America/New_York") 
    RDROpen := open
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high ,text="open price\n" + str.tostring(RDROpen), textcolor=color.white)
```

Thanks